# Корректно ли употреблять выражение "в дисбаланс входят"? Можно ли войти в дисбаланс?

Tags: стилистическая-сочетаемость

> Чаще всего в дисбаланс входят два метаболических гормона: инсулин и
> лептин.

Answer (score 1):

**"Войти в дисбаланс"** - это разговорное сокращение полноценной формулировки **"войти в состояние дисбаланса"**. Сокращение довольно часто используемое (и на мой взгляд - вполне допустимое), хотя и менее академичное, чем полный вариант.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Если ответ устраивает Вас, Вы можете отметить его как принятый.